# Tokenization for Google's Public Word2Vec

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tokenize, word2vec

I'm trying to tokenize my text in a way that is compatible with Google's pretrained word2vec https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/ however I could not find any code associated with the preprocessing nor training here.  I did find this link: https://github.com/dav/word2vec but it seems it also does not have preprocessing.  For example, in Google's word2vec they have vocab items like `####.##` which I assume means four numbers followed by a dot followed by two numbers.  I have managed to produce a tokenizer which produces somewhat the expected format but it would be nice to have something official.  Anyone know of anything?

Comment: I've not seen any authoritative summary of how text was preprocessed/tokenized... so teams reusing those vectors have had to mimic what's apparent in the tokens themselves. (Of course, note also that the word-vectors are from a circa-2012 archive of news articles - so new coinages & drifting word-senses since then won't be captures, and the senses may not match non-news domains like informal posts, fiction writing, etc.)

Comment: Right, the stuff I am dealing with is not too vulnerable to drift - I am mainly concerned with things like date formatting `##/##/####`, currency formatting `$ #,###.##` and a couple phrases like `per_annum`.  But maybe it is time to retrain for ourselves.  Thanks for your comment.